# Bada - Integrating Maps API to my application

Tags: mobile, maps, bada

I'm trying to integrate Maps to my Bada application. I've tried deCarta but unfortunately it comes with an ad. There is an ad on each form that displays a map and it's not pleasant.

So, can you please recommend me another maps API that will work well with the Bada platform. Does Google Maps API or Yahoo's service go along well with Bada? Or is there a way to remove the ad on deCarta's maps (on the free version)?

Any help, comment and such will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

Please don't remove the ad - that would be a violation of the terms of service. You could always pay to use the API and then you will never have to deal with ads on your application.

What is the part of the advertisement that you don't like. It would be great if you could give suggestions on how you would like to see the advertisements presented in the application.

Comment: The problem with the ad is, in the country where I am, there is only one ad. And that ad is very irrelevant to the audience of the application. Plus it is displayed in English, not in native language. So it's just a colorful rectangular box at the top of my app and just occupies space.

Comment: Moreover, I believe there is a problem with the AdManager class deCarta provides, or maybe it's my fault. But whenever I click on the ad, a browser launches. When I exit the browser, back to my app, the app crashes. Any fixes you guys can think of? Or has anyone tried Google/Yahoo/etc Maps API before on Samsung's Bada platform?

Comment: Hey Murat - thanks for the feedback I will pass it on to the engineering team and see if I can get some answers. You can also ask your question in developer zone forum hosted by deCarta - it is more likely to get you help on using the deCarta APIs.

Comment: Hey Murat - there is only one ad because you are still in staging and development. When you go into production the ad is served up from a much larger and geographically appropriate ad pool.

Comment: Hey Steve - thanks for the reply! =) I've already posted a similar question to the forum, it's here http://developer.decarta.com/web/guest/forums/message_boards/message/99304

Comment: The post is titled "deCarta Maps - crashing on certain actions". Hope there comes a fix soon ^^ looking fw for news..

Comment: You should have received an email with the news. Please let me know if you don't.